# How to refresh data in a page every 1 hour and when the tab receives focus in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, focus, onfocus

I was able to implement the auto-refresh every hour in Angular using `interval` and `Subscription`.

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {

   const source = interval(3600000); // Refresh Every 1 hour 
   this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.fetchNewData());

}


fetchNewData () {

    // Fetch New data and bind it to the View
}
```

To implement on tab focus, I used the below code:

```
@HostListener('window:focus')
onFocus(event: FocusEvent): void {
   this.fetchNewData()
}
```

The problem is, the `onFocus` method is triggered only when I make a click event on the webpage. 
How do I detect `onFocus` without any click on the webpage by the user?

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that, you will store time in local storage for the very first instance. And every next time, you need to perform difference with the current time and the past time that is stored.

```
ngOnInit() {
     if (!local storage.getItem("pastTime") {
         startTime = getMilliSeconds(hrs, min, sec)
        local storage.setItem("pastTime", startTime)
     }
     interval = localStorage.getItem("pastTime") - getMilliSeconds(hrs, min, sec)
    setInterval(this.timeOut(), interval);
}
```

In timeOut function,

```
timeOut() {
    // Call your data
    localStorage.setItem("pastTime", getMilliSeconds(hrs, min, sec));
    // Changing your pastTime in above statement. Since, you want to continue it every one hour. 
    interval = localStorage.getItem("pastTime") - getMilliSeconds(hrs, min, sec)
    setInterval(this.timeOut(), interval);
}
```

To get, milliseconds:

```
getMilliSeconds (hrs, min, sec) {
    return((hrs*60*60+min*60+sec)*1000);
}
```

Hope you understood what's happening. On init, we will set local storage value for the first time. And every time, we will perform difference between  local storage value and  current time. And that difference is sent to setInterval(). Once you call timeOut(), we set pastTime once more in local storage and so setInterval() also.I have no computer this point of time with me. So, it's all done without computer.  If you get some issue, that must be some minor one and can solve that.